# How do I force my Canon dSLR (800D) to take a photo?

Tags: canon, dslr, focus, camera-settings

I noticed when I went out early in the morning to take some landscape photography that sometimes when the image was "dark", the camera would not attempt to take the photo. I tried changing from a number of different modes (manual, auto, landscape, TV, etc. etc.) however it seemed that because the camera was unable to focus well on the target or wasn't positive that the camera was focusing onto the target that it would then attempt to focus, fail, and give up with capturing.

Is there a reason for this? I had manually focused using a focus ring and had the same issue with a standard 18-55mm kit lens as well as th 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II USM lens. Is it because of the camera model itself or a setting within the camera?

Comment: What focus mode (One Shot, AI Focus AF, AI Servo AF) is the camera in, what focus mode (AF/MF) are the lenses in, and what is Custom Function 12 "Shutter/AE lock button" set to?

Comment: I suggest that you need to watch some tutorials regarding shutter speed, aperture, and ISO. and the different focusing modes you have.

Comment: If your lens is in manual mode and the camera is in something other than easy/auto mode, it should take. I suggest trying program (P) mode as this will automate the exposure but not try to be too clever. If your lens has full time MF (as one of mine does) you can still switch it to manual only, and would need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your camera refuses to take the photo, it's usually because you have set it to AF + One shot mode. In such situation it needs to lock on the subject and you can see it struggling by flashing red light instead of a solid red (with a beep).
To get around this, you either need to focus manually or use some kind of external lighting (flash, lamp, whatever) to help the camera to achieve focus.